# Show that every non zero element of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ generates $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$p$ be a prime number and $\mathbb{Z}_p$ denote additive group of integer modulo $p$. I need to prove that every non-zero element of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ generates $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

### My Approach :

$$\mathbb{Z}_p = \{ 0,1,2,...p-1 \}$$

Let $k$ be any non-zero number in $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Any $x \in  \mathbb{Z}_p$ can be written as $x \equiv (p+y)k$,

where $y \in [0,p-1]$ , So any $x = \langle k \rangle$.

Can someone help me validate whether my approach is correct?

Comment: yes @reuns, since p is prime  { (p+y)k } / p $\in$ {0,1,2,3...p-1 }.

Comment: I don't see the need for the $p$ in $x$, since
$$[x]_p=[(p+y)k]_p = [pk+yk]_p=[pk]_p+[yk]_p=[0]_p+[yk]_p=[yk]_p$$
so it'd suffice to say $x=yk$ for some $1 \leq k \leq p-1$ and $1 \leq y \leq p-1$.But I don't see how this shows that *any element in $(\Bbb Z_p,+)$ has order $p$*, which is the goal!

Comment: You are right, p doesn't need to be in x. I am not very thorough with these concepts.

Comment: The solution is for a given $k$ to search for the smallest $m > 0$ such that $p \ |\ mk$. Since $p$ is prime then ..

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easy, higher level proof:

Let $x\in\mathbb{Z}_p$, $x\neq 0$. Obviously the order of $|x|>1$. By Lagrange's theorem $|x|$ divides $p$ and since $p$ is prime then $|x|=p$. In particular subgroup generated by $x$ has $p$ elements and thus is equal to whole $\mathbb{Z}_p$ (which also has $p$ elements).

Answer (score 0):

**Big Hint:**

$$|[m]_n| = \dfrac{n}{\gcd(m,n)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Take any integer $n\in\{1,\dots,p-1\}$, then $n$ and $p$ are coprime. Then, by Bézout's identity, there is $u,v\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $un+vp=1$, or $un=1-vp$. Therefore,
\begin{align}
[un]&=[1]\\
[(2u)n]&=[2]\\
\vdots&=\vdots\\
[((p-1)u)n]&=[p-1]\\
[(pu)n]&=[0].
\end{align}